# Use formula stored in table with help of a button to create number in textbox using MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, formula

I have a textbox called [Age] and when I press the button [AgeRoll] it need to put out an randomly rolled age into [Age] (ps:this is a rpg database)

For several races this is a different formula.

I managed to pull up the correct formula the only problem is it get read like text instead of being calculated as a number.

What needs to happen the formula it get from my table need to be calculated and give the result of that calculation as a number.

This is the code I am using in when you click the button:

```
Dim AgeMemory As Variant
Dim Raceid As Variant
Raceid = [Race ID].Value
AgeMemory= DLookup("AgeRol", "Race table", "[Id] =" & Raceid)
Age.Value = AgeMemory 'changes the value of Age into that of AgeMemory 
Age.SetFocus
```

Agerol is a field in the table "Race table" that is text
Age is a textbox in the form that is an integer (number)

This gives the error that AgeMemory is the wrong type of data (it not being a number but text instead)

When I look through in the debug window the value of AgeMemory is the formula I want to use, but as a text not a number that is the result of the formula it shows now.

One of the formulas it is returning to me is:

```
(16+((rnd*20)+1))
```

Very short version, I need a number instead of the formula I am getting now.

Answer (score 0):

VBA has an `Eval` function that evaluates formulas given as string

```vb
Debug.Print Eval("(16+((rnd*20)+1))") '==> 31.1109502315521 
Debug.Print Eval("(16+((rnd*20)+1))") '==> 27.6684803962708
Debug.Print Eval("(16+((rnd*20)+1))") '==> 22.7912492752075
```

---

```vb
Dim Formula As String
Dim Raceid As Long

Raceid = [Race ID].Value
Formula = DLookup("AgeRol", "Race table", "[Id] =" & Raceid)
Age.Value = Eval(Formula)
Age.SetFocus
```

Comment: Thank you. the Eval () function did the job perfectly. I changed  Age.Value = AgeMemory into Age.Value = Eval(AgeMemory) and works like a charm.

Comment: Why not Clng or CInt? Dlookup always returns null or text.

Comment: Because the OP stored a formula in the table.